# If all monotone subsequences of a sequence $S_n$ are convergent, then $S_n$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Would someone verify my proof:

> Assume by contradiction that $S_n$ is not bounded from above then for any $M>0$ there exist $n_1\, \mathrm{s.t.}\,S_{n_1}>M$. Next, choose $M=S_{n_1}$, then since $S_n$ is not bounded from above, there exist $n_2\, \mathrm{s.t.}\,S_{n_2}>M=S_{n_1}$. Continuing this way we get an increasing subsequence $S_{n_k}=S_{n_1},S_{n_2},S_{n_3},\cdots$
>   as $M\to\infty$ we get $\lim S_{n_k}=\infty$, since $S_{n_k}$ is monotonic subsequence, we get a contradiction.

Comment: similarly if Sn is not bounded below

Comment: There is an issue : you found $n_1$ with $S_{n_1} > M$. Then you found $n_2$ with $S_{n_2} > S_{n_1}$. Why should $n_2 > n_1$ hold? If it did not hold, then you don't have a subsequence. You have to be careful in your choice of $n_2$ to finish. Finally, you did get the increasing subsequence $S_{n_1} ,S_{n_2}$ etc. : how do you know this increases to infinity? For all you know this coul also be a bounded monotonic sequence, providing no contradiction.

Comment: Recall that for any sequence $(s_n)$ , there is a monotone subsequence of $(s_n)$ whose limit is $\limsup s_n$. Since this subsequence is bounded (above), $\limsup s_n$ is finite. Can you see why this implies $(s_n)$ is bounded above?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the same symbol $M$ repeatedly for different values. Also, if you re-name them as $M_1, M_2,...,$ you have not guaranteed that $S_{n_i}$ or $M_i\to \infty$ as $i\to \infty.$ You can let $M_1$ be arbitrary and $S_{n_1}>M_1,$ and then let $n_{j+1}>n_j$ such that $S_{n_j+1}>M_{n_j+1}=1+S_{n_j}.$

More simply, let $n_1=1$ and let $n_{j+1}$ be the least (or any) $n>n_j$ such that $S_n\ge 1+S_{n_j}.$ By induction on $j$ we have $S_{n_j}\ge S_{n_1}+(j-1)=S_1+(j-1).$

Comment: To the proposer: You had the right idea.